# VBA Filter combobox on userform with search suggestions

Tags: vba, excel, filter, combobox

I have created an excel userform with some comboboxes, attached a document with the problem but stripped down to the basic problem.

I figured out how i can filter/autoupdate my comboboxes and decrease the input list while i start typing in the list. However as soon as i select an item i get the following error: "Unable to get the CurrentRegion property of the Range class". I have tried many different solutions to get rid of the problem. But still can not figure out this final error. Even when I try to use "Range" instead of "CurrentRegion" I get these errors.

Since i want to apply this feature to all comboboxes on my userforms i have put everything in a class event.

I have already found some stuff online but these were basically comboboxes on a worksheet. I like to actively update the data on a userform. I think I have applied all stuff I found online in the code which I now have, but still need to solve this final issue.

[this is my example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k42mmr5tolq63qf/combobox_filter.xlsm?dl=0)

Thank you very much!

Best Regards, Marcel

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents myCBox As msForms.ComboBox
Dim data As Range

Private Sub myCBox_Change()
Set data = filter.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
' filter.Activate
With myCBox
   .DropDown

    ' FILTER
    list.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & .Value & "*"

    ' COPY
    filter.Cells.Clear
    list.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=filter.Cells(1, 1)

    Set data = filter.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    num_rows_2 = data.Rows.Count

    ' UPDATE COMBOBOX
    .RowSource = "filter!A2:A" & num_rows_2

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There are issues with `CurrentRegion` e.g., not being able to use it in a User-Defined Function. One post I read suggested Activating the sheet before referring to its CurrentRegion. Another possibility is to use LastRow and LastColumn fields, e.g. `LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. Lots of examples of that on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I activate the sheet I get the same error. When I use your suggestion of using LastRow for a known range I get the next error: "autofilter method of range class failed" which is the same 1004 runtime error. Furthermore when the values are not in the list I get the caption of the column, where I do like to get an empty value.

Comment: With the LastRow suggestion, I may not have been clear. I meant you could use it as part of an alternative approach to defining the area to filter. You will of course need to define the whole range, not just the last row. I don't know how you tried to do this, so not sure what the issue is. Again, there's lots of examples out there. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks again for the response, I am aware that there are many possibilities and I tried already many of these before raising the question. When setting the range for the autofilter I get the same error. I don't think the problem is in here. When I select an item in the combobox. I get this runtime error "1004", despite using currentregion or range. Have you seen my example files? Perhaps this could clarify it a bit.

Comment: Can anyone help me regarding above topic?